# map function returns a list of Unit instead of Char

Tags: android, kotlin, if-statement, lambda

why this function returns a list of Unit type instead of returning [c,c,c,c] list

```
fun convert(name:String) {
  val list = name.map {
    if (it == 'a') {
        return@map
    } else { it+1 }
  }
  println(list)
}


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  convert("bbbb")
}
```

Comment: what's the expected result of `return@map`? and the expected result for "babb"?

Comment: I know that the result of return is Unit but the string that I give to it in the main function doesn't have 'a' character so I expect that the else statement will always be invoked

Comment: Ah, I was asking whether `return@map` was meant to skip current iteration or break the entire mapping, to suggest a working solution

Comment: Thanks for reply , the return@map will only skip the current iteration of map function so only for one character , but as I said it was never invoked only else statement was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in the code is that the `return@map` statement inside the `map` function causes the function to return `Unit` type. To fix this, you can use `mapNotNull` instead of `map` to filter out the 'a' characters and then perform the transformation. Here's the modified code:

```kotlin
fun convert(name: String) {
    val list = name.mapNotNull {
        if (it == 'a') {
            null
        } else {
            it + 1
        }
    }
    println(list)
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    convert("bbbb")
}
```

Comment: but the string that I gave to it doesn't have 'a' character , so it should always invoke the else statement , why it invokes the if statement instead ?

Comment: I understand your concern. The issue is that the `return@map` statement is causing the entire `map` function to return `Unit` type, regardless of whether the condition is met or not. To fix this, you can remove the `return@map` statement and use `mapNotNull` to achieve the desired behavior.

Comment: BTW, does my answer work?

Comment: Yes it works, thank you so much , I finally get it .